Poisson distribution coverage probability for confidence interval.
I have been trying to solve this problem 9.24 of Statitical inference by Casella and Berger. I was able to understand in the theory that confidence interval for Poisson distribution is based on chi-square distribution.However, I am unable to find Coverage probability.
